# Number theory with sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, divisibility

The sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,.....$ is defined as:
\begin{cases}
x_0 = 2 \\
x_k =2\cdot x_{k-1}^2-1 &\text{for every }k>0\\
\end{cases}
Prove that if an odd prime number $p$ divides $x_n$, then $2^{n+3}$ divides $p^2-1$

---

My idea was to firstly treat simple cases like this:

If $n=0$, then $x_0=2$ doesn't have any odd divisors.

If $n=1$, then $x_1=7$. It has only one odd prime divisor, $7$ and $2^{n+3}=2^4=16$ divides $p^2-1=7^2-1=48$

.........

From here, my idea was to apply some sort of induction but induction doesn't work too well with prime numbers so this is where I got stuck with this idea.

Another idea was to write $x_n$ in its polynomial form and making it easier to prove what we want. I think that induction might work here but I still didn't manage to do it. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Fun fact. *Mathematica* gives the solution  $$x_n=\cos \left(2^k \arccos 2\right)$$

Comment: @Raffaele How is it possible? According to your formula, $x_n \le 1$ whilst the sequence tends to $+\infty$

Comment: (I made a typo: $k$ is $n$). $\arccos 2\approx 1.31696 i$ is a complex number. But $x_2=\cos(4 \arccos 2)= 97$ becomes real (integer) again.

Comment: @Raffaele, does this kind of identity give clues about integer divisibility?

Comment: @NN2 No no. It's correct. If we want to use hyperbolic cosine, then it becomes $$x_n=\cosh \left(2^n \log \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)$$

Comment: @EduardoPoço It was just a curiosity. Who know the algorithm used by *Mathematica* to get the result in a format so weird.

Comment: @Raffaele : you used which mathematca function for obtaining this result? I know "RecurrenceTable" but it seems to me that it provides only numerical and not symbolical value.

Comment: @NN2 RSolve[{x[k+1]==2x[k]^2-1,x[0]==2},x[k],k]

Comment: @Raffaele: Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to the recursion is:

$$x_n = \frac{\alpha^{2^n} + \alpha^{-2^n}}{2}$$

Which can be shown by induction.

By the initial condition, we get $\alpha = 2 + \sqrt3$. Then:

$$x_n = \frac{(2 + \sqrt3)^{2^n} + (2 - \sqrt3)^{2^n}}{2}$$

Now things start to become weird. If you expand both terms in parenthesis, you can eliminate square roots because they are negative in the second expansion. Take a prime that divides this integer and use $r$ as an integer square root of 3 in the modulus p. I still can't prove it exists. But assuming it is true, we get:

$$\frac{(2 + r)^{2^n} + (2 - r)^{2^n}}{2} \equiv 0\pmod p$$

$$(2 + r)^{2^n} + (2 - r)^{2^n} \equiv 0\pmod p$$

$$(2 + r)^{2^n} \equiv - (2 - r)^{2^n} \pmod p$$

Multiplying both sides by $(2 + r)^{2^n}$ and then squaring:

$$(2 + r)^{2^{n + 1}} \equiv -1\pmod p$$

$$(2 + r)^{2^{n + 2}} \equiv 1\pmod p$$

We see an exponent for which we get residue 1 modulus p, and if it is the minimum one (the order), it must divide every other exponent which also gives 1 modulus p for the same base, in particular p - 1, which works for every base.

It is really the minimum one, because, if any other is the minimum, it needs to be in the form $2^k$, $k < n + 2$, because it must then divide $2^{n+2}$.

This is not possible because we would have $(2 + r)^{2^{n + 1}} \equiv 1\pmod p$ by squaring both sides of $(2 + r)^{2^k} \equiv 1\pmod p$ multiple times, and we know the truth is $(2 + r)^{2^{n + 1}} \equiv -1\pmod p$.

We now get:

$$2^{n + 2} | p - 1$$

Since p + 1 is also even, the product $p^2 - 1 = (p-1)(p+1)$ must be divisible by $2^{n+3}$.

Comment: Actually $r$ exists $\iff x\overset{12}{\equiv}\pm1$ which is incorrect. Just take $7|a_1$ and it won't do

Comment: Also it's not $-2^n$ in the exponent of $2-\sqrt{3}$. It shall be $2^n$

Comment: Oops.. sorry! Edited the answer.

Comment: No problem :) But it's in another place as well. In the beginning (the $\alpha$ thing) also note that they shouldn't both be $\alpha$ since they're not equal

Comment: Seems p + 1 must the source of most 2 factors when 3 is not a quadratic residue... but I cannot imagine how to make p + 1 arise in a solution. p - 1 is more common because of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Why the statement $2^{n+2} | (p-1)$ holds true from the paragraph "It is really the minimum one, because, if any other.... "?

Comment: The minimum exponent e should divide every other, in particular $2^{n+2}$. Only a power of 2 can do it, but we already know that with $2^{n+1}$ the residue will not be 1.

Comment: Because we know that $2^{n+1}$ is the order of $2+r$ modulo $p$ which means that it divides any other value k for which $(2+r)^{2^{n+1}}\equiv1(mod p)$

Comment: @EduardoPoço You're wrong. $$a_6= 2011930833870518011412817828051050497=5\times19\times307\times941\times733097$$ And for 307 that is a prime divisor of $a_6$ and 3 is not a quadratic residue mod $a_6$ but 307+1=308 has more than 2 different prime factors

Comment: @EduardoPoço ,very nice solution.I think that you are right.If 3 is not a quadratic residue we need to find something else,related to $p+1$.I think that you are pretty close

Comment: Yeah, there are cases where the existence of residue does not hold, but I don't remember any fact giving p + 1 being divided like the common one p - 1.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this solution. At least you haven't (explicitly) answered the points mentioned by @Aryaaaaan and my point (how you conclude $2^{n+2}|p-1$ ?).

Comment: @EduardoPoço  I have a question,why does $(2+r)^{2^{n+1}}\equiv-1$(modulo $p$)?   Probably is simple but I just don't get it

Comment: @NN2 $$(2 + r)^{2^{n + 1}} \overset{p}{\equiv} -1 \implies (2 + r)^{2^{n + 2}} \overset{p}{\equiv} 1$$ So by this it is clear that $Ord^{2+r}_p=2^{n+2}$ and since $\phi(p)=p-1$, $2^{n+2}|p-1$

Comment: @Aryaaaaan can you answer my question too, please?

Comment: @alien2003 Assume that we have $(2+r)^{2^{n+2}} \equiv 1 (mod p)$. From the Fermat's little theorem, we have $(2+r)^{p-1} \equiv 1 (mod p)$. You still can not deduce $2^{n+2} | p-1$. For example, what if $p = 3.2^{n+1}+1$ and $(2+r)^{3} \equiv 1 (mod p)$

Comment: Edited in the answer. @NN2, I got more details there too.

Comment: @EduardoPoço I think that I have found something very interesting.We know that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $2|\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ so $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $16|p^2-1$ which seems a lot like the problem.I don't know exactly how it can help but you might find a way to use it because it is very likely that we need to use it$

Comment: So what? We don't have a use for 2 being a quadratic residue modp

Comment: I know but maybe we can find the formula for 3 which might be similar

Comment: Good, you found $p^2 - 1$ in a statement! But, without n, we're still stuck. Note that, if one of p - 1 or p + 1 is divisible by a power of 2, the other is only divisible by 2 once. So, depending on the case, we will find $2^{n+2}$ dividing p -1 or p + 1.

Comment: Wait a minute. I think it is not correct at all for the prime factors for which 3 is not a quadratic residue modp. For example $19|a_6$ but $2^9\not|192^2-1$. As for 307 and 941 and 733097 which are the other prime divisors of $a_6$ for which 3 is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: @Aryaaaaan,so you are saying that the problem is wrong,not just the solution?I just want to make sure.You might be right

Comment: The solution is correct. We were just thinking about the missing case where 3 was not a quadratic residue mod p but seemingly the problem is incorrect in these cases (as I showed in my examples) and your example about 7 one of the cases where this is correct although there are incorrect cases as well (as for $a_6$ that I mentioned)

Comment: @Aryaaaaan If the problem is incorrect then all solutions are correct. :-)

Comment: @Aryaaaaan I checked and calculated multiple times and $19\nmid a_6$.I think that the problem isn't wrong after all.So do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @EduardoPoço I think that the problem isn't wrong, so can you help me by thinking about it a little bit more?

Comment: I am still trying to find the rest of the solution. I tested some cases, it does not seem to be wrong. Where did it came from?

Comment: @alien2003 &  @ Eduardo Poço I'm sorry I gave wrong numbers but it is still incorrect. Your sequence is OEIS-A002812 and there you can see that starting from $a_0$, we have $a_5=1002978273411373057$ and it is divisible by the prime number $13553$ for which $3$ is not a quadratic residue and $$13553^2-1=183683808=2^5 × 3^3 × 7 × 11^2 × 251$$ And hence it is not divisible by $2^8$.

Comment: @NN2 The problem's not thoroughly incorrect. It is still true for prime divisors of $a_i$ that are congruent to $\pm1$ $(mod12)$

Comment: @alien2003 could you tell us how you got this problem?

Comment: I got it from a book.I don't know the solution or the sorce of it

Comment: Could you at least tell us about the name of this book?